# Client side Image presentation optimization

Tags: javascript, image, optimization

I have designed a long web page and there are many photos in one column from top to bottom listed one by one.

In order to create a high-level interection with the client, I want those photos loaded when the client scroll-down to the page. The more the go bottom, the more photos are loaded.
For Instance -> mashable.comn)

Waiting for your gold helps/advices for fast web pages.

regards bk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[lazy load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) (jquery)

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your quick help. Bu am I missing something, I did not get the taste of mashable.com's styled image loading on lazy load example...